# Find matching rows and return column value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I have 2 tables and I want to match the row in table A to the matching row in table B and return the Grade cell on the matched row from Table B.

Table A

| P | M | D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 1 |

Table B

| P | M | D | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | P |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | P |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | P |
| 0 | 3 | 1 | M |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | M |
| 0 | 1 | 3 | D |

I've tried googling, and searching, but either don't understand it or it doesn't do what I want. I'm not an expert in Excel, any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Neil

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formulas/xlookup-with-multiple-criteria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

[image]

Formula in `I2`:

```
=FILTER(D2:D7,BYROW(A2:C7=F2:H2,AND))
```

Here I used what is called an ETA-LAMBDA syntax. If you so happen to use an old(er) version of Excel, you can try to apply `MMULT()` too since you are simply comparing arrays that are within the same order:

```
=INDEX(D2:D7,MATCH(3,MMULT(N(A2:C7=F2:H2),{1;1;1}),0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `XLOOKUP()` with a delimiter in between each of the lookup values this quite achievable, here is what I have tried:

[image]

---

```
=XLOOKUP([@P]&"|"&[@M]&"|"&[@D],Table2[P]&"|"&Table2[M]&"|"&Table2[D],Table2[Grade],"NA")
```

---

Or, Using `Boolen` Logic within `XLOOKUP()` function:

[image]

---

```
=XLOOKUP(1,([@P]=Table2[P])*([@M]=Table2[M])*([@D]=Table2[D]),Table2[Grade],"NA")
```

---

**Note:** One can achieve the same output using `INDEX()`+`MATCH()` function if they are not using `MS365` or `Excel 2021`

---

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the rows in the table are unique, you can also use the [`DGET`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/dget-function-455568bf-4eef-45f7-90f0-ec250d00892e) function:

```cpp
=DGET(A1:D7,D1,F1:H2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Came across this as I posted....
https://exceljet.net/formulas/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Table A is in columns A to C, and your Table B is in columns F to I.

-- Use the below INDEX and MATCH FORMULA in column D

```
=INDEX(I:I,MATCH(A2&B2&C2, F:F&G:G&H:H, 0),0)
```

[image: Refer to this image for the clarity]

- MATCH will match the combination of values in different cells (A2&B2&C2) to the complete table B (F:F & G:G & H:H) and find the row number where it will find the match. In the below example, it will return 5 (as the first row of table A is the match for row 5 in table B)
- Now INDEX will give you the value of that row (in the below example row 5 in for column I:I)

*Index (I:I, 5, 0)  = value of that cell - which is the grade in this case* (keep the last parameter 0
here)